# Google Glass - Creating an options menu, nothing happens when item is clicked

Tags: android, menu, menuitem, google-glass, google-gdk

I am creating an app for Glass that displays a list of saved items (RememberItem). Each item has its card, and when you tap it, a menu appears with the following options: Get directions (launch google nav to the location of saved item), delete (remove the item from the list). 
However, nothing happens when we tap on the menu options.

Here's the code:

```
package com.adrianavecc.findit;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Handler.Callback;
import android.os.Message;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

import com.adrianavecc.findit.adapter.ScrollAdapter;
import com.adrianavecc.findit.db.SqlHelper;
import com.adrianavecc.findit.domain.RememberItem;
import com.adrianavecc.findit.util.RememberUtils;
import com.google.android.glass.app.Card;
import com.google.android.glass.app.Card.ImageLayout;
import com.google.android.glass.widget.CardScrollView;

public class Find extends Activity implements Callback {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ArrayList<String> voiceResults = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
    String tag= voiceResults.get(0);
    RememberItem item=SqlHelper.getInstance(this).findRememberItem(tag);
    if(item!=null){
        List<RememberItem> items=new ArrayList<RememberItem>();
        items.add(item);
        displayRememberItems(items);
    } else{
        if(RememberUtils.EVERY_THING.equalsIgnoreCase(tag)){
            List<RememberItem> items=SqlHelper.getInstance(this).findAllRememberItem();
            displayRememberItems(items);
        }
        else{
            displayFailureView();
        }
    }
}

private void displayFailureView() {
    Card fail = new Card(this);
    fail.setText(R.string.storefailhead);
    fail.setFootnote(R.string.storefailfoot);
    fail.setImageLayout(Card.ImageLayout.FULL);
    fail.addImage(R.drawable.storefailbackground);
    View failView = fail.getView();
    setContentView(failView);
}
private Card createCardOfRememberItem(RememberItem item) {
    Card card = new Card(this);
    card.setText(item.getTag());
    card.setFootnote(String.format("%tc", item.getAddedDate()));
    card.setImageLayout(ImageLayout.FULL);
    card.addImage(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(item.getImagePath()));
    return card;
}
private void launchGoogleMap(RememberItem item) {
    Location location=item.getLocation();
    Intent intent=RememberUtils.getGeoIntentFromLocation(location);
    Find.this.startActivity(intent);
}
private void displayRememberItems(final List<RememberItem> items) {
    List<Card> mCards = new ArrayList<Card>();
     for(RememberItem item: items){
         Card card=createCardOfRememberItem(item);
         mCards.add(card);
     }
    CardScrollView mCardScrollView = new CardScrollView(this);
    final ScrollAdapter adapter = new ScrollAdapter(mCards);
    mCardScrollView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            Card card=(Card)adapter.getItem(arg2);
            RememberItem item=SqlHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).findRememberItem(card.getText().toString());
            openOptionsMenu();

        }
    });

    mCardScrollView.setAdapter(adapter);
    mCardScrollView.activate();
    setContentView(mCardScrollView);
}

private void showSucessDeleteCard(RememberItem item){
    Card card = new Card(this);
    card.setText(R.string.object_delete);
    card.setImageLayout(ImageLayout.FULL);
    card.addImage(R.drawable.finditlogobg);
    setContentView(card.getView());
    Handler handler=new Handler(this);
    handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 3000);
}

@Override
public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
    finish();
    return false;
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.saveditemmenu, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuitem, RememberItem item) {
    switch (menuitem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_getdirections:
            launchGoogleMap(item);
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_delete:
            SqlHelper.getInstance(getApplication()).deleteRememberItem(item);
            showSucessDeleteCard(item);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuitem);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You must override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) which is the event and then call  onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuitem, RememberItem item) from that method.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is too late. Can you try this please

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER){
        Log.d("TOUCH","DPAD_CENTER");
        this.openOptionsMenu();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```